# Typescript error: Type Observable<Object> is not assignable to type

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack

I'm learning the MEAN stack and I'm stuck on a piece of code that used to work, but for reason today it seems to not want to work for me.

I'm getting an error: "Type Observable is not assignable to type Observable. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?

Here is the course.service.ts file where the error presents itself:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import {Course} from './course'; 
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'; 
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

    @Injectable() export class CourseService {

      constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

      readAll(): Observable<Course[]> {
        return this.httpClient
          .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');   }

    }
```

Here is course.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from '../course';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  course: Course;

  @Input()
    courseItemCss: string;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.course) {
      this.course = <Course> {};
    }

  }

}
```

Here is the interface course.ts:

```
 export interface Course {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
}
```

course.component.ts:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Course} from '../course';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css']
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  course: Course;

  @Input()
    courseItemCss: string;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.course) {
      this.course = <Course> {};
    }

  }

}
```

course.manager.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import {CourseService} from '../course.service';
import {Course} from '../course';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-manager',
  templateUrl: './course-manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-manager.component.css']
})
export class CourseManagerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  courses: Array<Course>;
  courseServiceSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService) {
    this.courses = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.courseServiceSub = this.courseService.readAll().subscribe(courses => {
      this.courses = courses;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.courseServiceSub) { // if subscription exists, unsubscribe from it.
      this.courseServiceSub.unsubscribe(); // make sure to unsubscribe or may cause memory leaks which makes app slower.
    }
  }
}
```

I know it's something simple but I can't figure it out right now.
Any advice would help.
thanks!

~jb

Comment: Opps.  Here it is:

Comment: i think you can just try `return this.httpClient.get<Course[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');   }` to strong type your API answer.

Comment: Thanks Yanis-git.  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

as specify on comment of original question, on this case you can strong cast httpClient observable like this :

```
@Injectable() 
export class CourseService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    readAll(): Observable<Course[]> {
        return this.httpClient
            .get<Course[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');   
        }
}
```

By this way, instead to receive `Observable<Object>` you will receive `Observable<Course[]>`

---

You can have another case who force you to apply some transformation from your request answer to fit on your model, on this case you should use `map` operator. Will looks like this :

```
@Injectable() 
export class CourseService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    readAll(): Observable<Course[]> {

        return this.httpClient
            .get<MyType[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').pipe(map(myAnswers => {
                    /**
                     * Map operator is dedicated to transform original data to formated data who fit on your expected output.
                    **/
                    const myTransformedAnswer = [];

                    myAnswers.forEach((item) => {
                        myTransformedAnswer.push({
                            id: item.id,
                            title: item.foo,
                            description: item.bar
                        });
                    });

                    return myTransformedAnswer;
            }));   
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thing is that httpClient returns `Observable<HttpResponse<Course[]>>`, not `Observable<Course[]>` directly, so there is your type mismatch.

Also you can do:

```
return this.httpClient
    .get<Course[]>.('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
```

So when you'll do something more with what it returns, you'll get type also in your `readAll()`

So your `readAll()` should like this:

```
readAll(): Observable<HttpResponse<Course[]>> {
    return this.httpClient
        .get<Course[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');   }
```